# Copy columns in Excel based on header

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a column from one sheet ("Data1") to another sheet ("Calc"). I then want to copy another column from another sheet ("Data2"), if that column header is the same as the column from "Data1" sheet and paste that in "Calc" sheeet, second column.

I would like to put this in a loop so it copies all of the columns in "Data1" sheet and the corresponding columns in "Data2" sheet to "Calc" sheet.

Data1 sheet looks something like this:

[image: Data1]

Data2 sheet looks like this:

[image: Data2]

And I would like Calc sheet to look something like this:

[image: Calc]

I pretty new to VBA so any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you want to copy both `AAA`'s, if they are both present? Do you need both, as they are identical?

Comment: Yes I need them both. They are identical in this case, but the data in the columns are different. In my actual file, the only thing that will be identical are the column headers in the Data1 and Data2 sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This will clear the Calc sheet, then check the number of columns in Data1 and copy columns from Data1 and Data2 only if they match.

```
Sub UpdateCalcSheet()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet

    Dim NumCols As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Data1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Data2")
    Set ws3 = Sheets("Calc")

    ws3.Cells.ClearContents

    NumCols = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    t = 1

    For i = 1 To NumCols
        Set IsCol = ws2.Rows(1).Find(ws1.Cells(1, i))
        If Not IsCol Is Nothing Then
            ws1.Columns(i).Copy ws3.Columns(t)
            t = t + 1
            ws2.Columns(ws2.Rows(1).Find(ws1.Cells(1, i)).Column).Copy ws3.Columns(t)
            t = t + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```